# Get categories from save_post hook

Tags: categories

I am trying to develop a hook when save_post to get the categories but for new posts I don't get any categories and for updated posts I get the categories "before" updating the post. This should be super simple but I can't figure it out. I have been hours trying to find a solution.

This is the minimal code that I am trying to run:

```
add_action('save_post', 'test' , 10, 3 );
   
   function test($post_id, $post, $update){
       $categories=get_the_category($post_id);
       var_dump($categories);
   }
```

I am also trying to get things from $_REQUEST but its only content is this:

```
Array
(
    [_locale] => user
)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This looks like it should work, so perhaps something else is going wrong. Are you 100% sure you're actually saving some category information with the post? Also are you sure it's not a custom taxonomy, but regular Wordpress categories?

Comment: Also, if you're using a standard Wordpress, where/how are you seeing the output from var_dump? On a clean Wordpress with Gutenburg, this code doesn't work as it interferes with the way the page loads.

Comment: Yeah, I am just using categories, marking/unmarking them and updating the post, that's all I am doing. I am using the Gutenberg editor.

Also, I am actually using file_put_contents("log.txt",print_r($categories,true)); to see what is in that variable. Not the most elegant way but it lets me debug easily!

Answer (score 1):

After doing much more search... it looks like the save_post hook does not run after the post categories are updated so it will only show the categories that the post had before the update (or no categories for new posts).

I found that I need to use this hook and then everything inside my function is updated:

```
add_action('rest_after_insert_post', 'test' , 10, 2 );
```

I had no idea that was the hook I needed to use. I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use the `wp_after_insert_post` hook which fires once a post, its terms and meta data has been saved.

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_after_insert_post/

```
add_action('wp_after_insert_post', 'test' , 10, 2 );

function test( $post_id, $post ){
  $categories = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'category' );
  error_log( print_r( $categories, true ) );
}
```

use the `get_the_terms` function to get all the categories but make sure to add the right category term name. For Posts, WordPress comes with the category as the default for all posts.

You need to `error_log` the values since this hook will not be seen on the front-end but rather you can use the `debug.log` file to see all the results.

See: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/